# Live streaming of h.264 using HTML5 in internet explorer 9

Tags: html, video, stream, live, h.264

I trying to find a way to stream live video in internet explorer 9. The videos will be encoded in h.264 (I have to use this encoding) and the user will only be using internet explorer 9. I did some research and every post I found are quite old. At the time, not a lot of information was available and I couldn't find any satisfying answer. Also, I thought that maybe browser support evolved since.

My video source for the moment is RTSP but I could change to anything if I need too (http or something, I don't really know much about that).

So does anyone know if there is anyway to do what I want to do in IE 9 (using HTML5, we already have a flash/silverlight/solution). Preferably no plugin needed to play the live stream.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `<video>` tag supports RTSP streams: you can use:

```
<video src="rtp://domain.com/stream">
    Your browser does not support RTP streams.
</video>
```

This would be a good starting point, I haven't tested this in IE9 but I know it works ok in Chrome/FF.